# Send POST request from Java server (jetty)

Tags: java, post, jetty, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a POST request from a Java server (Jetty) to another server `https://example.com/api/test` with parameters `userId`, `token` and `status`.

In Java I am invoking the method below:

```
sendNotification("https://example.com/api/test", "test1", "test", 200)
```

and I see on the logs that it successfully prints:

```
Sent request to https://example.com/api/test with userId test1 and token test
```

However, in the `https://example.com/api/test` logs I receive no request at all.

However, when I try the command below, I do receive the request perfectly:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"userId": "helloo@apptium.com", "token": "asdfasdf", "status": 200}' https://example.com/api/test
```

What is wrong?

**Java method:**

```
private void sendNotification(String endpoint, String userId, 
                              String token, int status) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(endpoint);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)con;
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);

        byte[] out = ("{\"userId\":\"" + userId + "\",\"token\":\"" + token + "\",\"status\":" + status + "}").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int length = out.length;

        http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        http.connect();
        try {
            log.warn("Sent request to " + endpoint + " with userId " + userId + " and token " + token);
            OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
            os.write(out);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            log.error(APImessages.ERROR_500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should you close the outputStream after the write operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call "os.close()" to finish sending the request body to the remote server